# Route Codeigniter URL to another port

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-url

I want to Route Codeigniter URL to another port on the same domain

All request towards:

```
http://www.example.com/api/testing
```

are pointed to:

```
http://www.example.com:4500/api/testing
```

Here 4500 is the port i'm used

I tried with the following, but not working:

```
$route['api/(:any)'] = ":4500/api/$1";
```

Comment: You can do that before the request comes to the application via htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

simply use in htaccess:

```
Redirect "/api/" "http://www.example.com:4500/api/"
```

No need to set any routes in CI.